# Проблемы с json

Tags: java

У меня возникала проблема с обработкой json, есть ссылка:

```
http://arizona-recovery.react.group/desktop/ping/Arizona/ping.json
```

Код запроса:

```
    private String connect(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
        String result = in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
        //System.out.println(result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["query"] not found.
at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:572)
at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:859)
at Controller.dataParse(Controller.java:47)
at Controller.start(Controller.java:16)
at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

Для обработки использую `JSONObject`

Буду рад за любую помощь с вашей стороны

Comment: приведите ваш JSON, который вы парсите и код, которым вы парсите.

Comment: `return url;` может `return result;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте проще: заставляйте сериализатор превращать ответ сразу в объект. Я использую lombok для генерации геттеров, сеттеров и др. стандартных методов, вы можете добавить их сами,если не хотите пользоваться lombok . В качестве десериализатора возьмите гугловую библиотеку Gson. Она очень простая в использовании и очень производительная. Скачать ее можно отсюда https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
Дальше дело техники. Любой онлайн сервис с легкостью превратит в джейсон в джава-класс. Создаем эти классы, чтобы подкинуть их десериализатору. Остается только создать метод, который будет отправлять запросы и преобразовывать их в объекты уже созданных нами классов. Поскольку не очень хочется вязаться на конкретный класс, для большей универсальности используем дженерики. Теперь в нашем метод 2 параметра: урл, на который нужно отправить запрос, и целевой класс для десереализации ответа. Из метода получаем готовый объект. Разумеется, здесь создаются лишние объекты, да и рест-клиентов более, чем достаточно (чтобы не писать самому логику отправки запросов), например, тот же ретрофит. Но, поскольку вы решили сделать это именноо таким способом, оставлю как есть, это тоже работает.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {        
        QueryWrapper result = connect("http://arizona-recovery.react.group/desktop/ping/Arizona/ping.json",QueryWrapper.class);
        System.out.println(result);        
    }

    private static <T> T connect(String url, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
            final String json = in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
            return new Gson().fromJson(json, clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}

@lombok.Data
class QueryWrapper {
    private Query[] query;
}

@lombok.Data
class Query {
    private String number;
    private String password;
    private String port;
    private String ip;
    private String name;
    private String online;
    private String maxplayers;
}
```